Dynamically create partition function daily monthly
I am trying to create a create partition function dynamically for each day and month from the existing table. Not sure how to get boundary date inside the function dynamically. It will be good if I have get one extra empty boundary as first boundary.
Here is the sample script:
use master
go
alter database DB_Partition set single_user with rollback immediate
drop database DB_Partition
create database DB_Partition
go
use master
go

go
use DB_Partition
go
--create schema [C1810429]
go
use DB_Partition
go
--Create target table, copy from your script except dbname
CREATE TABLE [STYTOTAL_RAW](
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)
)
GO


--fill some initial data 
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2(7) = '2024-04-01 00:00:00.0000000'
WHILE @DateTime <= '2024-10-22 00:25:33.9999999' -- select getdate() 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [STYTOTAL_RAW] ([STYLE],[InsertedDateTime])
  SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1,@DateTime
 SET @DateTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @DateTime)
END
GO


---
Declare @Tbl_Name nvarchar(128)
set @Tbl_Name='STYTOTAL_RAW'

Declare @schema_Name nvarchar(128)
set @schema_Name='dbo'

/*
Declare @Boundary_Date datetime2(7)

select CAST(CAST(YEAR(InsertedDateTime) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(MONTH(InsertedDateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME2(7)) from [STYTOTAL_RAW]
group by CAST(CAST(YEAR(InsertedDateTime) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST(MONTH(InsertedDateTime) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/01' AS DATETIME2(7))
*/

Declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = 'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_'+@schema_Name+'_'+@Tbl_Name+'] ( [datetime2](7)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('
select @cmd
 
 /*
--Create function, copy from your script

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_myDateRange        ( [datetime2](7)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
'2024-03-01 00:00:00.0000000',
'2024-04-01 00:00:00.0000000',
'2024-05-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-06-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-07-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-08-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-09-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-10-01 23:59:59.9999999',
'2024-10-21 23:59:59.9999999' 
)
GO
*/

--Declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
set @cmd = 'CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_'+@schema_Name+'_'+@Tbl_Name+'] AS PARTITION PF_'+@Tbl_Name+' ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);'
select @cmd

--Create SCHEME, copy from your script
--CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_myPartitionScheme  AS PARTITION PF_myDateRange  ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);

Any suggestion or SQL function that can do this.
Thanks for your help.

I have got it and it is working. If I add DD instead of month it is creating by day. Posting here for any improvement as well.
use master
go
alter database DB_Partition set single_user with rollback immediate
drop database DB_Partition
create database DB_Partition
go
use master
go

go
use DB_Partition
go
--create schema [C1810429]
go
use DB_Partition
go
--Create target table, copy from your script except dbname
CREATE TABLE [STYTOTAL_RAW](
    [STYTOTALID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [STYLE] [decimal](5, 0) NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IsCurrent] [bit] NULL,
    [DELDATTIM] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [DELFLAG] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_C1810429_STYTOTAL_RAW] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [STYTOTALID] ASC,
    [STYLE] ASC,
    [InsertedDateTime] ASC
)
)
GO

set nocount on
--fill some initial data 
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2(7) = '2024-04-01 00:00:00.0000000'
WHILE @DateTime <= '2024-10-22 00:25:33.9999999' -- select getdate() 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [STYTOTAL_RAW] ([STYLE],[InsertedDateTime])
  SELECT  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%8)+1,@DateTime
 SET @DateTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @DateTime)
END
GO

--------============== create partition function

Declare @Tbl_Name nvarchar(128)
set @Tbl_Name='STYTOTAL_RAW'

Declare @schema_Name nvarchar(128)
set @schema_Name='dbo'


 
--Create date partition function with increment by month. 
DECLARE @DatePartitionFunction nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_'+@schema_Name+'_'+@Tbl_Name+'] ( [datetime2](7)) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('
DECLARE @min_date datetime2(7);
DECLARE @max_date datetime2(7);

select @min_date=min(DATEADD(MM, -1, [InsertedDateTime])) from [STYTOTAL_RAW];
select @max_date=max(DATEADD(MM, -1, [InsertedDateTime])) from [STYTOTAL_RAW]; 

--select @DatePartitionFunction
--select @min_date, @max_date


WHILE @min_date < @max_date

BEGIN 
--     SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(DATEPART(year, @min_date)*10000 + DATEPART(month, @min_date)*100 + DATEPART(day, @min_date) AS varchar(18)) + '''' + N', '; 
       SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + convert (NVARCHAR(128),@min_date) +'''' + N', '; 

     SET @min_date = DATEADD(MM, 1, @min_date); 
END 

--SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + CAST(DATEPART(year, @min_date)*10000 + DATEPART(month, @min_date)*100 + DATEPART(day, @min_date) AS varchar(18)) + '''' + N');'; 
SET @DatePartitionFunction += '''' + convert (NVARCHAR(128),@min_date) +'''' + N');'; 

EXEC sp_executesql @DatePartitionFunction; 
--print  @DatePartitionFunction
GO

Declare @Tbl_Name nvarchar(128)
set @Tbl_Name='STYTOTAL_RAW'

Declare @schema_Name nvarchar(128)
set @schema_Name='dbo'

Declare @PS_cmd nvarchar(max)
set @PS_cmd = N'CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_'+@schema_Name+'_'+@Tbl_Name+'] AS PARTITION PF_'+@schema_Name+'_'+@Tbl_Name+' ALL TO ([PRIMARY]);'
EXEC sp_executesql @PS_cmd
--print @PS_cmd
go

